# Change Button Text Color When Clicked in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I know this question is asked frequently and many of answers are correct, I have my code in which I'm facing an issue. I have radio buttons on which when user click the button background color and text color changes. The background color is changed as I expected but the text color turns blue area when the button is clicked. I have coded it to change white color when click but when I click the button it changes the text area to blue, I'm confused that where I'm doing mistakes. My code is,

```
 self.selectedTitleColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.selectedBackgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

self.unselectedTitleColor = [UIColor blackColor];
self.unselectedBackgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

- (IBAction)House:(id)sender {

[sender setSelected: ![sender isSelected]];
[self.flat setSelected:NO];
[self.lowerP setSelected:NO];
[self.upperP setSelected:NO];
[self.farmH setSelected:NO];
[self.pentH setSelected:NO];
[self.roomB setSelected:NO];


[self updateButtonColors];
```

}

```
-(void)updateButtonColors {
if (self.house.selected) {
    [self.house setTitleColor:self.selectedTitleColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.house setBackgroundColor:self.selectedBackgroundColor];

    House=_house.titleLabel.text;
    ImageViewD = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",House];

    NSLog(@"HHHH  %@",ImageViewD);

} else {
    [self.house setTitleColor:self.unselectedTitleColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.house setBackgroundColor:self.unselectedBackgroundColor];
        }
```

}

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change button type in storyboard from **system** to **custom** .

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot . @KKRocks

Answer (score 0):

Best to give all property into Storyboard itself. You can take two images for your color and set into **UIButton**'s **backgroundImage** state.

Check out below image for same.

[[image: Normal State]]

[image: Selected State]

I have a binding button with below method and its code:

```
- (IBAction)clicked:(id)sender {
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
    btn.selected = !btn.selected;
}
```

Below are images which I took it for reference.

[image: Red.png]

[image: Green.png]

Hope it will help you.

Comment: i didn't get it can u explain more? @Nirmalsinh

Comment: You need to take two images with plan color. I took red and green color image to make changes for particular state. And also set text color which we want.

Comment: how it will change the color when button is clicked? @Nirmalsinh

Comment: you can take two image with plan color.

Comment: I have added red and green color png file in updated answer. You can take any color which you like.

Comment: Bro i'm not getting how to add two images at background at same time? @Nirmalsinh

Comment: You check state config, which is second option in image. If its default, then set property for default. If its selected then set it for selected state. And in method, we just change the button state. So accroding to state, it will display the image and its property.

Comment: Above answer works fine for me, thanks for ur answer also :) . @Nirmalsinh

Comment: I already define custom into my screen shots, if you noticed.

Comment: oopsss i'm really sorry. @Nirmalsinh

Comment: Its ohk. Good point is that you will get your answer of your issue.