# Not changing text color of buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

When I am clicking the **UIButton**, I want it to change its text color. Moreover, I have set a view below each button, with the button having a bottom margin of 7. I have done it so to have a highlighted effect for the button that is clicked by changing the background color of the view. Nothing is happening on clicking the button. Here with attaching a screenshot

[image]

I want it to be exactly like this when clicked

[image]

```
- (IBAction)setMenubtn:(UIButton *)menubtn:(id)sender {
      [self.menubtn setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      [self.contactsbtn setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      [self.favoritesbtn setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      [self.topView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:2/255 green:115/255 blue:168/255 alpha:1]];
      [self.topview2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:226/255 green:226/255 blue:226/255 alpha:1]];
      [self.topview3 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:226/255 green:226/255 blue:226/255 alpha:1]];
   }

   - (IBAction)setContactsbtn:(UIButton *)contactsbtn:(id)sender {
       [self.menubtn setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       [self.contactsbtn setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       [self.favoritesbtn setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       [self.topView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:226/255 green:226/255 blue:226/255 alpha:1]];
       [self.topview2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:2/255 green:115/255 blue:168/255 alpha:1]];
       [self.topview3 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:226/255 green:226/255 blue:226/255 alpha:1]];
  }

  - (IBAction)setFavoritesbtn:(UIButton *)favoritesbtn:(id)sender {
       [self.menubtn setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       [self.contactsbtn setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       [self.favoritesbtn setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       [self.topView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:226/255 green:226/255 blue:226/255 alpha:1]];
       [self.topview2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:226/255 green:226/255 blue:226/255 alpha:1]];
       [self.topview3 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:2/255 green:115/255 blue:226/255 alpha:1]];
   }
```

It is showing this output

[image]

Comment: Try by adding .f as suffix. Like-  [UIColor colorWithRed:226.f/255.f 
       green:226.f/255.f blue:226.f/255.f alpha:1];

Comment: what is the use of `sender` here

Comment: Checkout my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45210659/change-button-text-color-when-clicked-in-ios/45210852#45210852

Comment: is this correct `(IBAction)setMenubtn:(UIButton *)menubtn:(id)sender` or else

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik what else it should be

Comment: it should be -- > (IBAction)setMenubtn:(UIButton *)menubtn

Comment: Relevant: You are trying to implement [Android PagerTab Strip](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTabStrip.html) for iOS. You can easily do that using [XLPagerTabStrip](https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip) for iOS. Why reinvent the wheel? You can easily get the output like [This](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip/master/Example/instagram.gif). For ObjC, you can use [PageMenu](https://github.com/PageMenu/PageMenu)  for Obj C

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik nothing is happening

Comment: can you update the question is easy to resolve

Comment: And also in  colorWithRed method, divide by 255.0, not 255.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik As long as she has connected the IBAction correctly, DataType of Sender does not matter as she is not using `sender` instance to do operations, she is using IBOutlets directly. And OP, Are you sure you have connected the method to the Button action? Place a breakpoint in a method and see if it is being called? Are IBOUtlets connected?

Comment: @NSNoob yes that was the only problem. But now it is showing some different output

Comment: @AashimaAnand Sorry you're unclear. What was the problem? IBOutlet not being connected or IBActions not being connected? And what is the different output? Judging by your code, it most definitely will not show the output you want. It will definitely change background of whole button thanks to setBackgroundColor.

Comment: @NSNoob IBActions were not connected and I have updated my question with the screen shot

Comment: @NSNoob The text color is not changing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150595/discussion-between-aashima-anand-and-nsnoob).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First check if you Buttons are IBOutlets and really connected to the Buttons in the Storyboard.

If the Buttons are not IBOutlets or connected to the buttons in storyboard, your code will not be able to change an attribute for example self.menubtn.

- Be sure the IBOutlets only connected once.
- Be sure the IBAction are connected only once and to the correct Buttons with, for example, touchUpInside

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code to show you how to change UIButton color when being clicked:

```
button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setSelected:YES];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [button setTitle:@"Button Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonActive.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Comment: This is just to demonstrate

Comment: What is it going to demonstrate when the x,y,width,height and graphics are unavailable

Answer (score 0):

Why are do hard code. In Github already made this type of custom control. 
You can customize the layout as you like and it is easy to implement.

[HMSegmentedControl](https://github.com/HeshamMegid/HMSegmentedControl)

Comment: Third Party resource isn't what is asked. You can recommend them in Comments (I Did) but don't post them as answers. Third Party resource recommendation questions are off topic